# Java applets and setting up an exception for a PC that is not a web server

Tags: java, exception, applet

I have being trying to get a clock applet to run on my locate PC outside of netbeans but the when I load the web page to run the applet I get “Application Blocked by Java Security”.  Googling I then create a self-signed certificate thinking that would solve the problem.
I opened a command window and changed directory to where the jar and class were and the created the key and certificate.

```
cd C:\DEV\clock\classes
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias selfsigned -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore  keystore.jks

Enter keystore password: <password>
Re-enter new password: <password>
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  PC129.aa.dfdd.nasa.gov (this is fake but matches the pattern I used)
Etc.

C:\DEV\NelsonsPrograms\clock\clock\classes>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\keytool" -selfcert -keystore keystore.jks -alias selfsigned -validity 3650

Enter keystore password: <password>

C:\DEV\NelsonsPrograms\clock\clock\classes>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\jarsigner" -keystore keystore.jks threeClock.jar selfsigned

Enter Passphrase for keystore: selfsigned
jar signed.

Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a times tamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2025-06-21) or after any future revocation date.
```

I this tried to start the web page again but this time I got “Application Blocked.  Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running”.  I again googled and they all seem to basically say that you need to still add a Java exception for you PC to make the applet run.  But all the examples seem to be www.foo.com examples with either a full path name to the web/applet directory, domain name, or full domain name which all seem to be www or http addresses.  So what is the correct input for a PC that is not a web server or has a www address setup for it?  I don’t think I need the full path to the applet directory included in the exception name since I only saw that in one example.

So lets say this is my PC info:  PC129 is the host name.  Network: aa.dfdd.nasa.gov

So what should the the exception name be?

The SAs here have no idea since they always add exceptions for web servers that have www web addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The SA finally came by and after lots of combinations we found that adding the following exception to the java site list will allow the applets to run.

file:/C:/DEV/NelsonsPrograms/clock/clock/classes/

The full path name was required to the location where the applet and web page was located otherwise the applet would be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Correction, while the signed jar is running correctly, web pages that try to just run the XXX.class don't run.  The applet is displaying the layout, but nothing is running in it.  I think the local input file is being blocked so there is no data to display.  So make a jar, self sign it, and run the jar from the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I turned on the java console via Java Control Panel - Advanced tab to see why the aosClock.class version didn't work while the signed clock.jar did and as you can see it’s the security stuff again stopping the applet from working.  It’s stopping the applet from reading in the clock time data.  Googling seems to indicate that I would have to insert grant code into the applet, but since the signed jar version works fine on my PC I will use that to test. I don't want to add extra stuff that is not needed in the applet when running on a real web server.  The jar way also seems to be the standard way to do web applets now anyway.

aosClock: Thread-14: Forcing garbage collection...
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\DEV\NelsonsPrograms\clock\clock\classes\aqua_aos_times" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.initializeHeaders(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at singleClock.run(aosClock.java:679)